# ${d\over dx}f(2x+1)=\sin(4x^2-1)$, then is $f$ differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Question:**  ${d\over dx}f(2x+1)=\sin(4x^2-1)$, then is $f$ differentiable?

Since $\varphi:x\rightarrow2x+1$ is bijective, I thought that $f$ is differentiable. But, I wanted a precise solution, so I tried to use the chain rule in order to get the form of $df/dx$.
(And since it is from the past calculus mid-term exam, I cannot write the function $\varphi$ and finish the proof)

When we use the chain rule, by substituting $t = 2x-1$ we might say that ($df/dx=2$)
$$ {df(t)\over dt}{dt\over dx}={d\over dx}\sin(4x^2-1)=8x\cos(4x^2-1)$$, so we can determine $df(t)/dt$. However, since we cannot ensure the existance of $df(t)/dt$ we cannot actually step into the procedure.

Using the definition of derivatives can be a possible way to solve this.
$$sin(4x^-1)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(2x+1)-f(2a+1)}{x-a}\\ =\lim_{x\to 
a}\frac{f(2x+1)-f(2a+1)}{(2x+1)-(2a+1)}\cdot\frac{(2x+1)-(2a+1)}{x-a}\\$$
But, again, we don't know whether $$\lim_{x\to 
a}\frac{f(2x+1)-f(2a+1)}{(2x+1)-(2a+1)}$$ has a value or not.

I also thought of the solution analogous to the 'proof' of the chain rule, which uses epsilon function to approximate the function values(epsilon function is defined as for $h\ne0: f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(a)h+\epsilon(h)\cdot h$, for $h=0: \epsilon(0)=0$), but I stuck in here.

Is there any idea to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Erm... I'm sorry, but the question, as stated, is absolute nonsense. If you give a derivative, it *is* the derivative. A sensible formulation of the same question might be: if $g(x)=f(2x+1)$, and $g$ is differentiable, is $f$ differentiable? But that is trivial.

Comment: I agree that it is quite weird, but the problem is from our past mid-term. So, I want to know how to write the solution for 'trivial thing' mathematically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x):= f(2x+1)$. Then $g$ is differentiable. Since we have

$$f(x)=g(\frac{x-1}{2}),$$

$f$ is differentiable.

Comment: I have a question, sir. How can I ensure that $g(\frac{2x-1}{2})$ is differentiable from the condition that $g(x)$ is differentiable?

Comment: Let $h(x)= \frac{x-1}{2}.$ Then $h$ is differentiable, hence, by the chain rule, $g \circ h$ is differentiable.

Comment: I see. Thanks, sir.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you're somewhat close.  For, $\varphi$ is not just bijective: it's also smooth, and has a smooth inverse.  That's it's a diffeomorphism.  The point being, that your function *is* going to wind up being differentiable.

Furthermore, there's no real need to re-prove the chain rule, which is something whose proof you can easily look up.  Alot of people have a hard enough time just remembering the  *statement* of the chain rule, especially in some of its different forms.  ( One of my fellow PhD students once caught my advisor not knowing the chain rule in one of its guises.  But that is neither here nor there.)

Comment: Thanks very much for the advice, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the intention of this problem is the following:

Let $h(x) = f(2x+1)$. Then, according to FTC we conclude

$$h(x) = \int_0^x\sin(4t^2-1)\; dt\text{ is differentiable}$$

Besides this, $x(u) = \frac u2 - \frac 12$ is differentiable. Hence, $f(u) = h(x(u))$ is differentiable  wrt. u, because according to the chain rule we have

$$\frac{df}{du} = \frac{dh}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{du}$$